# Get Youtube video storyboard using ID/URL

Tags: youtube

Every Youtube video has a *storyboard*. I'm not sure it is the right word but I'm referring to the thumbnails that appear when you hover over the timeline of the player.
Examining the network tab in Chrome console, I saw it arrives as a single image of all the storyboard images concatenated

For example for [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGc_NfiTxng&ab_channel=TobiasKthmn) this is the [storyboard](https://i.ytimg.com/sb/cGc_NfiTxng/storyboard3_L1/M0.jpg?sqp=-oaymwENSDfyq4qpAwVwAcABBqLzl_8DBgin3OnwBQ==&sigh=rs%24AOn4CLCiYNchSFSPt8oWjArv9cWbw6tCEg)

I was wondering if there is a way to get the storyboard using the video URL / video ID?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're referring to the short three-ish second video that happens when you hover over the thumbnail? Like [this thing](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7074781)?

Comment: Nope, I'm referring to the images that are displayed when you hover over the video's timeline once you are in the video page

Comment: @bluesummers AFAIK, this is not documented, I doubt this is possible, but, one way could be web-scraping the page and get the URL, (*being genuinely curious here:*) - have you tried anything?.

Comment: I didn't go that route since you'll need to also execute the JS code, so standard scraping will not work, you'll have to either scrape through something like Selenium or have some middleware to execute the JS code and those don't scale nicely. I prefer right now to download the video and create the storyboard myself or to find a way to get the storyboard strictly with HTTP